# Haxe, differentiate anonymous function at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, function, function-pointers, anonymous-function, haxe

I'm trying to differentiate anonymous functions like:

```
function() { trace("WOO"); }
```

from the other ones ('named'?) like

```
var _FUNC:Dynamic = function() { trace("WOO"); }
```

The reason I want to do that is because I can't compare between two anonymous functions, because they are two different ones.

To help me make things clearer, consider the following quick example.

```
var _TEST:Dynamic = function(a:Dynamic):String {
  var _TESTA:Dynamic = function() { trace("WOO"); };
  var _TESTB:Dynamic = _FUNC;
  return (a == _TESTA) + ", " + (a == _TESTB);
}
```

If I run `_TEST(_FUNC);`, I'll get back `"false, true"`. Even though they are the same function, they are NOT the same object.

Is there a way to compare those such that functions that they are the same if they perform the same task?

Is there a way to serialize functions? So that maybe I can compare the serialized representations and see if they share the same 'code'.

Answer (score 4):

A few clarifications:

- The first two samples you have posted are virtually identical. The only difference is that you have assigned the second to a static var. You could have used a static function directly with the main difference that in that case the function is not changeable If you want to make it so you should add the `dynamic` modifier.
- Starting from the latest version you can have local named functions:

  ```
  static f() { function a() { trace("hi"); }; a() }
  ```
- To properly compare methods you should use [`Reflect.compareMethods()`](http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#compareMethods). Sometimes Haxe creates closures around functions and that can break equality.
- You can compare function *references* but not the function *bodies*. So the answer is no, you can't compare function that are generated in different statements but do the same thing.
- You cannot serialize functions.
- You can maybe find some platform specific way to deal with this situation or Macro may apply too (to create function signatures) but I think it is easier to redesign your code. Another option is to adopt a lib like [hscript](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hscript) for those calls that need to be comparable and serializable.